# how can I do a switchMap and get the diferent responses in the subscription?

Tags: rxjs

How can I achieve the following using RXJS?
I have 3 requests each dependant on the previous, and I need all responses in the subscription.

```
this.httpService.request1(paramsObj).pipe(
    switchMap((response)=>{
        return this.httpService.request2({...response})
    }),
    switchMap((response)=>{
        return this.httpService.request3({...response})
    })
).subscribe(([response1, response2, response3]) => {
   // somehow access all responses here while each response is dependeant on the previous one
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return switchMap inner results in an array like forkJoin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71323064/return-switchmap-inner-results-in-an-array-like-forkjoin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to mannually pass it down like below

```
this.httpService.request1(paramsObj).pipe(
    switchMap((res1)=>{
        return this.httpService.request2({...res1}).pipe(map(res2=>[res1,res2]))
    }),
    switchMap(([res1,res2)=>{
        return this.httpService.request3({...res2}).pipe(map(res3=>[res1,res2,res3]))
    })
).subscribe(([res1, res2, res3]) => {

})
```